# .NET Core 7 environment variables in published Docker container

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, docker-compose

I have a simple ASP.NET Core 7 Web API that I use to fault find some machinery on several sites. I am trying to get it to work in Docker to make it easier to distribute updates.

In Visual Studio 2022 in `launchSettings.json` I can do this to pass some connection strings as environment variables:

```
"Docker": {
  "commandName": "Docker",
  "launchBrowser": true,
  "launchUrl": "{Scheme}://{ServiceHost}:{ServicePort}/ScanstationTest",
  "publishAllPorts": true,
  "httpPort": 5001,
  "environmentVariables": {
    "ReportConnectionString": "Server=1.2.3.4;Initial Catalog=Report;Persist Security Info=True;User Id = user; Password=<its a secret>;Encrypt=False",
    "SorterAConnectionString": "Server=5.6.7.8\\SQLEXP2012; Database=SorterA;User Id = user; Password=<its a secret>;Encrypt=False"
  }
```

No problems.

However when I deploy the image.

I have tried all the methods described here: https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/set-environment-variables/ to set the variables in docker compose. If I inspect the container that visual studio creates for debugging it doesn't have the environment variables I created. It seems .NET Core doesn't use the global environment variables but something specific to the dotnet process.

How do I set these environment variables when I deploy the image?

I am using

```
Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ReportConnectionString")
```

to read the variables in. Is there different ways to read from global / user / process environment variables?

UPDATE:
The documentation for [Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.getenvironmentvariable?view=net-7.0) says that reading global environment variables is not supported on non-Windows systems so I need to find a way to set the dotnet process environment variable. How do I do set these?

I imagine I need a script or configuration file somewhere to copy the global environment variables to the process but I have no idea where these might live in a docker image.

This is the docker compose file:

```
services:
  reportapi:
    image: myprivaterepository/reportapi7:202307100307
    ports:
      - "5001:80"
    restart: always
    environment:
      - ReportConnectionString = Server=1.2.3.4;Initial Catalog=Report;Persist Security Info=True;User Id = user; Password=<its a secret>;Encrypt=False
      - HarmonySorterAConnectionString = Server=5.6.7.8\\SQLEXP2012; Database=SorterA;User Id = user; Password=<its a secret>;Encrypt=False
```

And this is the Dockerfile that Visual Studio generates

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:7.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["ReportAPI7/ReportAPI7.csproj", "ReportAPI7/"]
RUN dotnet restore "ReportAPI7/ReportAPI7.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/ReportAPI7"
RUN dotnet build "ReportAPI7.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "ReportAPI7.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "ReportAPI7.dll"]
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show how you're setting the environment variables. How can anyone help you with the non-working part if you only show the working part?

Comment: _"The documentation [...] says that reading global environment variables is not supported on non-Windows systems"_... where does it say that? Could you please attend to the previous comment and provide details, as in your actual YAML configuration. It could be a simple typo (and probably is). I have run many .NET projects in Docker with env vars being read correctly

Comment: Oops linked set not get documentation. Should be fixed now. I appreciate your help Phil. I'll try to put some more info together to capture my problem. When VisualStudio creates and deploys the container I can't see the environment variables from a command prompt in the container but they are loaded into the application and everythingworks. When I write my own docker compose I can see the environment variables in a command prompt but dotnet says "can't connect to server '  ' ". Will update with some screenshots when I get a minute.

Comment: Ugh! Seriously, just [edit] your question to include your docker compose YAML file

Comment: Done but I still don't think that is the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Phil but that does not help. I have already tried every combination with and without spaces, even quote marks, that I can think of. I tried creating env files and linking in the compose file and as an argument when I call docker compose. And I've tried the YAML map. All good ways of creating global environment variables. What I really want to know is how visual studio is setting the environment variable for the specific process rather than globally. If anyone has any insight into that specific question I would love to know the answer.

Comment: I tried it with your original YAML and it didn't work. Then I tried it with the YAML in my answer and it did. Not sure what else to say

Comment: in your question you say .NET Core 7 environment variables, is this problem on in .net 7 or is it the same issue with .net 6? just want to be sure if this is version specific or general issue.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax used for your `environment` mapping is incorrect. There should be no spaces around the `=` sign.

Use either

```yaml
environment:
  - ReportConnectionString=Server=1.2.3.4;Initial Catalog=Report;Persist Security Info=True;User Id = user; Password=<its a secret>;Encrypt=False
  - HarmonySorterAConnectionString=Server=5.6.7.8\\SQLEXP2012; Database=SorterA;User Id = user; Password=<its a secret>;Encrypt=False
```

or a YAML map

```yaml
environment:
  ReportConnectionString: Server=1.2.3.4;Initial Catalog=Report;Persist Security Info=True;User Id = user; Password=<its a secret>;Encrypt=False
  HarmonySorterAConnectionString: Server=5.6.7.8\\SQLEXP2012; Database=SorterA;User Id = user; Password=<its a secret>;Encrypt=False
```

See https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#environment

Comment: I was following this question, it works for me as well.